# can Membership Providers be request specific

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, multi-tenant

In a multi-tenant (seperate database per client) model is possible or even desireable to use either the Microsoft MembershipProvider or the SimpleMembership providers?

the original membership provider is configured from the web.config and the Simplemembershipprovider (in MVC4 template) has a method which initialises the database per application start rather than per session or request.

Is it the case that the membership/simplemembership providers are therefore tied into the application or inprinciple is it a sensible fit to change the database connection to point to the requesting clients database per request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We established that we needed to use dependancy injection to add custommembership providers per tenant request. Through thorough investigation it was apparent that we couldnt modify the connection for the membership provider and ensure it hadnt been remodified by another request prior to completion of the request. Due to its singleton design.

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with my custom membership provider:

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/

Create your custom `IAccountRepository` on top of the one in the SqlServer package. A lot easier than implementing your own provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen and implemented something very similar to that, based on code from  [ASP.NET: Supporting Dynamic Applications](http://cgeers.com/2009/10/24/asp-net-supporting-dynamic-applications/).

This is not the same as what you are asking - the goal here it to use the same membership database, but with a different Application Name for each client.

I am not sure how you can set the connection string dynamically though - [`SqlMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) does not expose that property. You might start with [`Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.provider.providerbase.initialize.aspx), but as you've said, it doesn't run on each request. There is also the option of creating your own provider, and creating an internal `SqlMembershipProvider` per request.

Comment: I can't comment on MVC4's provider - I don't know it yet. But I have this question open for a week now with no answer, and maybe I can offer some help...